# How does one get a hold of the details regarding a system/application crash

Tags: apport

Is there a way to generate a decent looking report with the /var/share/apport/*.crash files?

If not, how does one get a hold of the details regarding a past system error?

Answer (score 4):

The `apport-unpack` command will output human readable files into a directory provided a .crash file and the name of a directory.

`apport-unpack /var/crash/_usr_lib_gnome-settings-daemon_gnome-settings-daemon.1000.crash /home/surgemcgee/gnome_crash`

Answer (score 1):

And after you unpack it, run gdb to backtrace it.

`gdb pathToYourBinaryWhichCrashed CoreDump`

then:

`bt`

to see backtrace.

Note: *CoreDump* needs to be binary file in unpacked files directory from apport-unpack.